How to Write Unit Tests for GORM Repository Method with gomock?
I am trying to write unit tests for a GORM repository method using gomock to mock database interactions. However, I'm running into issues with nil pointer dereference errors. Below are the relevant parts of my code:
Repository Code:
package repositories

import (
    "github.com/CAVAh/api-tech-challenge/src/core/domain/entities"
    "github.com/CAVAh/api-tech-challenge/src/infra/db/database"
    "github.com/CAVAh/api-tech-challenge/src/infra/db/models"
)

type CustomerRepository struct {
    DB database.Database
}

func (r CustomerRepository) FindFirstByCpf(entity *entities.Customer) (*entities.Customer, error) {
    var customer models.Customer

    db := r.DB.Where("cpf = ?", entity.CPF)
    err := db.First(&customer).Error

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    result := customer.ToDomain()

    return &result, nil
}

Database Interface:
package database

import (
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

type Database interface {
    Create(data interface{}) error
    Where(query interface{}, args ...interface{}) *gorm.DB
    First(dest interface{}, conds ...interface{}) error
}

type RealDatabase struct {
    db *gorm.DB
}

func (rdb *RealDatabase) Create(data interface{}) error {
    return rdb.db.Create(data).Error
}

func (rdb *RealDatabase) Where(query interface{}, args ...interface{}) *gorm.DB {
    return rdb.db.Where(query, args...)
}

func (rdb *RealDatabase) First(dest interface{}, conds ...interface{}) error {
    return rdb.db.First(dest, conds...).Error
}


Unit Test Code:
package repositories

import (
    "testing"

    "github.com/CAVAh/api-tech-challenge/src/core/domain/entities"
    "github.com/CAVAh/api-tech-challenge/src/infra/db/models"
    gomock "go.uber.org/mock/gomock"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
)

func TestFindFirstByCpf_Success(t *testing.T) {
    ctrl := gomock.NewController(t)
    defer ctrl.Finish()

    mockDB := mocks.NewMockDatabase(ctrl)
    repo := CustomerRepository{DB: mockDB}

    entity := &entities.Customer{CPF: "12345678901"}
    customerModel := models.Customer{
        Name:  "John Doe",
        CPF:   "12345678901",
        Email: "john@example.com",
    }

    // Mock for returning the correct instance of gorm.DB
    mockGormDB := &gorm.DB{}
    mockDB.EXPECT().Where("cpf = ?", entity.CPF).Return(mockGormDB).Times(1)
    mockDB.EXPECT().First(gomock.Any()).DoAndReturn(func(dest interface{}) *gorm.DB {
        *dest.(*models.Customer) = customerModel
        return &gorm.DB{}
    }).Times(1)

    result, err := repo.FindFirstByCpf(entity)
    assert.NoError(t, err)
    assert.NotNil(t, result)
    assert.Equal(t, "John Doe", result.Name)
    assert.Equal(t, "12345678901", result.CPF)
    assert.Equal(t, "john@example.com", result.Email)
}

Error Message:
--- FAIL: TestFindFirstByCpf_Success (0.00s)
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference [recovered]
        panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference [recovered]
        panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x60 pc=0x5c06df]

goroutine 9 [running]:
testing.tRunner.func1.2({0x6a8860, 0x94d7c0})
        /usr/local/go/src/testing/testing.go:1631 +0x24a
testing.tRunner.func1()
        /usr/local/go/src/testing/testing.go:1634 +0x377
panic({0x6a8860?, 0x94d7c0?})
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:770 +0x132
go.uber.org/mock/gomock.(*Controller).finish(0xc0001f5950, 0x0, {0x6a8860, 0x94d7c0})
        /home/cava/go/pkg/mod/go.uber.org/mock@v0.4.0/gomock/controller.go:270 +0x25f
go.uber.org/mock/gomock.(*Controller).Finish(0xc0001f5950)
        /home/cava/go/pkg/mod/go.uber.org/mock@v0.4.0/gomock/controller.go:243 +0x37
panic({0x6a8860?, 0x94d7c0?})
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:770 +0x132
gorm.io/gorm.(*Statement).AddClause(0x0, {0x7837a0, 0xc0001abe70})
        /home/cava/go/pkg/mod/gorm.io/gorm@v1.25.5/statement.go:269 +0x7f
gorm.io/gorm.(*DB).Limit(0xc0001f59b0, 0x1)
        /home/cava/go/pkg/mod/gorm.io/gorm@v1.25.5/chainable_api.go:332 +0x85
gorm.io/gorm.(*DB).First(0xc0001abd80?, {0x6a2ec0, 0xc0001fe750}, {0x0, 0x0, 0x0})
        /home/cava/go/pkg/mod/gorm.io/gorm@v1.25.5/finisher_api.go:119 +0x4c
github.com/CAVAh/api-tech-challenge/src/infra/db/repositories.CustomerRepository.FindFirstByCpf({{0x783530?, 0xc0001abd80?}}, 0xc0000a4ee8)
        /mnt/c/Users/Cava/Documents/code/customer-service/src/infra/db/repositories/customer_repository.go:40 +0x115
github.com/CAVAh/api-tech-challenge/src/infra/db/repositories.TestFindFirstByCpf_Success(0xc0000d5520)
        /mnt/c/Users/Cava/Documents/code/customer-service/src/infra/db/repositories/customer_repository_test.go:101 +0x37a
testing.tRunner(0xc0000d5520, 0x7315f0)
        /usr/local/go/src/testing/testing.go:1689 +0xfb
created by testing.(*T).Run in goroutine 1
        /usr/local/go/src/testing/testing.go:1742 +0x390
FAIL    github.com/CAVAh/api-tech-challenge/src/infra/db/repositories   0.008s

I've tried several different approaches, like:
mockDB.EXPECT().Where("cpf = ?", entity.CPF).Return(&gorm.DB{Error: nil}).Times(1)
// AND
mockDB.EXPECT().Where("cpf = ?", entity.CPF).Return(mockDB).Times(1)
// AND
mockDB.EXPECT().Where("cpf = ?", entity.CPF).Return(mockDB.Where("cpf = ?", entity.CPF))

but I keep encountering this nil pointer dereference error. What am I doing wrong? How can I correctly mock the GORM database interactions to test this repository method?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
